# How to create an empty view (or array) and later insert data in it?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, view

This is because I am creating a procedure which generates items (by calling another function) which then finally needs to return me an array sort of collection including all the values.

I am thinking I can do it with a temporary table or View.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getAllStrings $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getAllStrings(IN idString varchar(256), OUT finalSeparate VARCHAR(256)) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT LENGTH(idString) - LENGTH(REPLACE(idString, ',', '')) INTO @noOfCommas;
               IF  @noOfCommas = 0 
              THEN 
                     SELECT idString;
              ELSE 
                    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v AS SELECT NULL AS SPLIT_VALUES WHERE FALSE;
                    SET @y = 1;
                    WHILE @y  <= @noOfCommas DO 
                       SELECT splitString(idString, ', ', @y) INTO @tempSeparate; 
                       SET  @y = @y + 1; 
                       INSERT INTO v (SPLIT_VALUES) values(@tempSeparate);
                    END WHILE; 
                    SELECT SPLIT_VALUES FROM v;
        END IF; 
END $$
```

It says that

> Target table v is not insertable-into

How do I do it? I even tried changing the algorithm to `merge` but it didn't work.

The one with a table works, but I am looking for a data structure that can hold it better, maybe @json, I don't know.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS splitString $$
CREATE FUNCTION splitString (
        x VARCHAR(255),
        delim VARCHAR(12),
        pos INT
        )
        RETURNS VARCHAR(255) deterministic
        RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
         LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
         delim, '') $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getAllStrings $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getAllStrings(IN idString varchar(256), OUT finalSeparate VARCHAR(256)) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT LENGTH(idString) - LENGTH(REPLACE(idString, ', ', '')) INTO @noOfCommas;
               IF  @noOfCommas = 0 
              THEN 
                     SELECT idString;
              ELSE 
                    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_SEP_STRINGS;
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP_SEP_STRINGS( SPLIT_VALUES VARCHAR(256));
                    SET @y = 1;
                    WHILE @y  <= @noOfCommas DO 
                       SELECT splitString(idString, ', ', @y) INTO @tempSeparate; 
                       SET  @y = @y + 1; 
                       INSERT INTO TEMP_SEP_STRINGS(SPLIT_VALUES) values(@tempSeparate);
                    END WHILE; 
                    SELECT * FROM TEMP_SEP_STRINGS;
        END IF; 
END $$
CALL getAllStrings('b, a', @multiple);
```

Comment: A view is not a table, it's a view into other table(s).  The view itself does not hold data, it merely returns data from the underlying tables.

Comment: @Ben is right at least for MySQL — views are like an alias or a macro. They only serve as a query against other tables. Views don't store any data. Your view `v` is not insertable because it has no `FROM` clause and in that way does not define a base table.

Comment: In fact, I am surprised it's accepted at all, because any SELECT query must have a `FROM` clause before it has a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Well, there are insert statements for the view, so that happens. But you might be right about MySQL as I've seen it on plenty, the insert statements, for SQL Server. Also, the create view query didn't give me any errors. Only the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

A **[temporary table](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/)** has been the best option for me yet. It gets deallocated when the session ends or the connection is closed (although you can drop it before that happens) and just gobbles up whatever data you give it.

No need to define its columns and stuff and you can probably use it anywhere via `SELECT` command such as with the `SQL IN` operator.

An example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
SELECT tree_id FROM TREES WHERE fruit_type='Apple';
```